# Как использовать public метод класса, экземляр, которого передан по ссылке в функцию другого класса, экземпляр, которого создается в QPluginLoader

Tags: qt

Пишу приложение, которое поддерживает плагины. В самом приложениии используется экземпляр некоего класса (`MyQObject`).

Надо чтоб любой плагин имел доступ к публичным методам этого класса. Проблема в том что в рантайме при попытке вызвать метод экземпляра этого класса приводит к ошибке

> "... symbol lookup error ... undefined symbol:
>   _ZN9MyQObject9testCalllEv".

NB: В метод плагина, передается ссылка на экземпляр класса и вызывается метод (приводит к ошибке). Причем значение свойства экземпляра класса получает без проблем.

Код демонстрирующий ошибку (Qt4) можно взять тут: [github](https://github.com/reeshkov/qt_tests/tree/master/test_plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто подключить заголовочный файл и объявить ссылку на класс, то почему-то таблица символов для этого класса не создается.

Проблема решена выносом класса MyQObject в отдельную библиотеку и использовании этой библиотеки в программе и плагине.

Как использовать и писать библиотеки: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application/ru